# How to append completion character depending on which is needed. Ruby Readline

Tags: ruby, readline

With Ruby Readline module we are able to have some auto_completion using tab. It's pretty simple to set up, take directories.

```
Readline.completion_proc = proc do |input|
  Readline.completion_append_character = '/' 
  Dir[input+'*'].grep(/^#{Regexp.escape(input)}/)
end
```

This is great for directories, as at the end of every tab completion we need a new / to start the next dir. What if we are trying to open a file though. having / at the end of /mydir/file.txt/ wouldn't work you would get complaints.

I'm not sure how to use a regex to get any file extension then append a space. Ones i have tried work on some files but if the file has many '.' it ends up giving false positives. If the folder contains a '.' in the name this also throws it off.

Comment: Append the `/` to each directory name of the proc's result instead.